# (Python) Passing multiple changes to URL

Tags: python

I have a list of several stock tickers:

```
ticker = (GE,IBM,GM,F,PG,CSCO)
```

That I want to pass to the URL in my python program.

```
url = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/FB.json"
```

I'm trying to pass a new ticker into the URL on each subsequent pass thru my program.  I'm struggling with how to pass each new ticker in the list of ticker into the URL as it loops thru the program. Program needs to grab a new ticker from the list and replace the one in the URL.

Example: After the first pass, program should grab GE from the list and replace FB in the URL and continue looping thru until all tickers have been passed to URL. Not sure how best to deal with the part of the program. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You would need a simple string formatting. See [the docs](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/python/1019/string-formatting#t=201608132053481825712).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import requests

url_tpl = "https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datasets/WIKI/{ticker}.json"
# Here your results will be stored
jsons = {}

for ticker in ('FB', 'GE', 'IBM', 'GM', 'F' , 'PG', 'CSCO'):
   res = requests.get(url_tpl.format(ticker=ticker))

   if res.status_code == 200:
      jsons[ticker] = res.json()
   else:
      print('error while fetching {ticker}, response code: '
            '{status}'.format(ticker=ticker, status=res.status_code))
```